# echo text to multiple files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

I am working on a bash script that uses pssh to run external commands, then join the output of the commands with the IP of each server.  pssh has an option -o that writes a file for each server into a specified directory, but if the commands do not run, you just have an empty file.  What I am having issues with is updating these empty files with something like "Server Unreachable" so that I know there was a connection issue reaching the server and to not cause problems with the rest of the script.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/user/tools/test-host"

now=$(date +"%F")
folder="./cnxhwinfo-$now/"
empty="$(find ./cnxhwinfo-$now/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -size 0 -printf '%f%2d')"
command="echo \$(uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if (\$7==\"min\") m=\$6; else {if (\$7~/^day/) {d=\$6;h=\$8;m=\$9} else {h=\$6;m=\$7}}} {print d+0,\"days\",h+0,\"hours\",m+0,\"minutes\"}'),  \$(hostname | awk '{print \$1}'), \$(sudo awk -F '=' 'FNR == 2 {print \$2}' /etc/connex-release/version.txt), \$(lscpu | awk -F: 'BEGIN{ORS=\", \";} NR==4 || NR==6 || NR==15 {print \$2}' | sed 's/ *//g') \$(free -k | awk  '/Mem:/{print \$2}'), \$(df -Ph | awk '/var_lib/||/root/ {print \$2,\",\"\$5,\",\"}')"

pssh -h $file -l user -t 10 -i -o /home/user/tools/cnxhwinfo-$now -x -tt $command
echo "Server Unreachable" | tee "./cnxhwinfo-$now/$empty"

ls ./cnxhwinfo-$now >> ./cnx-data-$now
cat ./cnxhwinfo-$now/* >> ./cnx-list-$now
paste -d, ./cnx-data-$now ./cnx-list-$now >>./cnx-data-"$(date +"%F").csv"
```

I was trying to use find to locate the empty files and write "Server" unavailable using tee with this:

```
echo "Server Unreachable" | tee "./cnxhwinfo-$now/$empty"
```

if the folder specified doesn't already exist i get this error:

tee: ./cnxhwinfo-2019-09-03/: Is a directory

And if it does exist (ie, i run the script again), it instead creates a file named after the IP addresses returned by the find command, like this:

192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 1

I've also tried:

```
echo "Server Unreachable" | tee <(./cnxhwinfo-$now/$empty)
```

The find command outputs the IP addresses on a single line with a space in between each one, so I thought that would be fine for tee to use, but I feel like I am either running into syntax issues, or am going about this the wrong way.   I have another version of this same script that uses regular ssh and works great, just much slower than using pssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty` should be an array, assuming none of the file names will contain any whitespace in their names.

```
readarray -t empty < <(find ...)

echo "Server unreachable" | (cd ./cnxhwinfo-$now/; tee "${empty[@]}" > /dev/null)
```

Otherwise, you are building a *single* file name by concatenating the empty file names.

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't used arrays before but this worked:

readarray -t empty < <(find ./cnxhwinfo-$now/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -size 0 -printf '%f\n')
echo "Server unreachable" | (cd ./cnxhwinfo-$now/; tee "${empty[@]}" > /dev/null)

I had to change my find command just a bit - \n instead of %2d!